# Push notifications with service workers in django

Tags: python, django, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to implement push notifications in my django web app. I'm new to service workers and I can't find any working examples of how to implement this in django. Has anyone managed to implement this in django? Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure it out as well, please check this libraires

https://github.com/web-push-libs

Haven't got the  time to test any of those yet, but it should be a good starting point, as there is a Python lib.